# Send email notification on ssh login using pam_exec

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, ssh, pam

I want to get notified for all the users who login using ssh to my ubuntu server.

Add the following line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
session required pam_exec.so  seteuid /usr/local/bin/ssh_alert.sh
```

In the file ssh_alert.sh, I have the following

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "open_session" ]
then
  exit 0
else
  {
    echo "User: $PAM_USER"
    echo "Remote Host: $PAM_RHOST"
    echo "Service: $PAM_SERVICE"
    echo "TTY: $PAM_TTY"
    echo "Date: `date`"
    echo "Server: `uname -a`"
    exec /usr/bin/python3 send_mail.py
  }
fi
exit 0
```

All the files have proper permission(0700) and they are executables.

**Whenever I login into the server neither the variables are printed, nor the mail is sent.**

The send_mail.py sends an email, when executed on its own.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you somehow log the output before the Python line, and confirm that it gets populated, like to a logfile? Also can you try to add the absolute/full path to `send_mail.py`?

Comment: send_mail is located in the same directory as that of script. logger does nothing.